# Using the URLconf defined in e_learning.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

this is my first time working with django and i'm getting this error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/student.html
Using the URLconf defined in e_learning.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
student [name='student']
courses
The current path, student.html, didn’t match any of these.
```

i know this question was asked before but the answers didn't solve my problem.

this is my views.py

```
def student(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentF(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect('/')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        form = StudentF()
    return render(request, 'student.html', {'form': form})
```

and this is urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('student', views.StudentF, name="student"),
]
```

forms.py

```
class StudentF(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name', 'phone', 'email', 'password']
        widgets = {'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'password': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   }
```

this is how i call my form from the navbar:

```
<a href="student.html" class="btn btn-primary py-4 px-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block">Join Now<i class="fa fa-arrow-right ms-3"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The urls are `student`, so you visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/student`. The template is named `student.html`, but this is what Django renders *internally*.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('student/', views.student_f, name="student"),
]
```

```
<a href="/student/" class="btn btn-primary py-4 px-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block">Join Now<i class="fa fa-arrow-right ms-3"></i></a>
```

This is how you `urls.py` and you navbar should look like.

> In your `urls.py`, it is important to always add a trailing slash to the end of a URL path. You can read about the importance of this [here](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/trailing-url-slashes-django). Also, it is never a good practice to use the same name for a function and a class. In this case, you used `StudentF` as the name of both your view function and your `ModelForm` class, which is bad programming practice.. You can read more about naming conventions in python [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) or [here](https://visualgit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/naming_convention.html)